# How to move tables from one dataset to another dataset in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-transfer

In the Big Query Data Transfer Service, I have linked Dataset 1 to the Search Ads 360 data transfer. Now I can see 20+ tables in Dataset1. Is it possible to move these 20+ tables to Dataset2 which will be dedicated to Search Ads data.

Comment: recreate the transfer service wth dataset2

Comment: Thankyou, but does it will remove the tables created under dataset1

Comment: transfer service doesn't delete anythig, you need to cleanup

Answer (score 1):

No, it is **not possible to move** the 20+ tables from dataset1 to dataset2 in **BigQuery**. Instead of moving the tables to dataset2, you can create a one time **copy of the dataset** in supported regions using the **Copy Dataset icon** or on a customized recurring schedule using **BigQuery Data Transfers** with Source Type as **Dataset Copy**. It does not delete any tables in dataset1. It just creates a copy of dataset1 in dataset2. Then, later [delete](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#deleting_tables) the unwanted tables from dataset1/dataset2 by using the **Delete icon** or querying. If you want to [copy a single table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#copying_a_single_source_table) from dataset1 to dataset2, use the **Copy icon** from the **source table**. But, the source and destination datasets must be in the same [location](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations). See [Supported Regions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#supported_regions) and [Copy Dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#setting_up_a_dataset_copy) for more information.